# export uv layout only edge select

Tags: uv, export, texture-paint-mode

[image]enter image description hereI need to export only some selected edges not the faces of them.

The problem is that they are not visible even in the UV map and therefore cannot be exported.

Is there a way to export only selected edges?

I want to simply export only the black outlines on my transparency texture and then apply them on the texture and simulate a toon outline on my model, here's the reason
and I need to export only the contours I need
You can obtain this black outline effect on the model by exporting the transparency of only the black lines in UV by inserting absolute 00, then eliminating all the other black lines and adding the erosion effect in a Photoshop program.
the problem that always affects me is to manually delete all the areas of the mesh if I could export it, only the selected edges everything would be easier, that's the point.

[image]

Comment: tbh i have no idea what you want to achieve and what the sense of this might be...!? maybe you wanna explain a bit more why you wanna do that?

Comment: Please show us a simple  example.. and .. in what format do you want to export, and for what purpose?

Comment: I want to simply export only the black outlines on my transparency texture and then apply them on the texture and simulate a toon outline on my model, here's the reason
and I need to export only the contours I need